# Android Studio Preview is different from the real device

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, preview

I have installed an AVD for my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge.
When I look to a layout at the android studio preview it fits the screen perfect. But it looks different on the real phone.

Device resolution is also at 2560x1440

**What is the problem?**

Screen settings AVD:

[image]

Preview settings Android Studio:

[image]

Screenshot Phone:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `RelativeLayout` with too many `Views` to fit the screen. Either you want to use `ConstraintLayout` to set the Views in a direct relation to each other or you put a `ScrollView` around your root layout. Either case there is only so much space to fill.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a ConstraintLayout. But I also want to know what I have to do, that the preview in android studio looks the same as on the device.